# Python `strptime` missing "T" and "Z" when printing?

Tags: python, utc, python-datetime

What am I missing here?

**Why does this...**

```
import datetime

start_date = '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
start_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

print(start_date_obj)
```

**...result in:** `2020-10-01 00:00:00`

**...instead of:** `2020-10-01T00:00:00Z` ?

Where is the "T" and "Z" in the output?

Comment: Note that when you call `print(datetime_object)`, the `__str__` method of the datetime object is called - this happens to give you isoformat with space as date/time separator. It's just a matter of display, that's all. If you want a string in a specific format, see my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Z denotes UTC, so you should parse to an aware datetime object using either `strptime` with the `%z` directive:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(dt)
# 2020-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

or `fromisoformat` with a little [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418):

```
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
print(dt)
# 2020-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

You can do the same thing when converting back to string:

```
out = dt.isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
print(out)
# 2020-10-01T00:00:00Z
```

`strftime` won't give you `Z` but for example `UTC`:

```
out = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z')
print(out)
# 2020-10-01T00:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. Apparently I need to convert from `datetime` object back to string(?) to make this print nicely?

```
import datetime

start_date = '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
start_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
start_date_printable = datetime.datetime.strftime(start_date_obj, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

print(start_date_printable)
```

**Results in:** `2020-10-01T00:00:00Z`